# CASE Statement with Dates in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a WHERE clause to look back 3 days when the day of the week is Monday by joining in the calendar table.

```
WHERE        
CASE WHEN calendar.DW = 2 Then (date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-3))
            AND GETDATE() ELSE
        date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-1))
            AND GETDATE()
            END
```

I am getting an error on the "BETWEEN" operator for the above. Is it possible to do what I am attempting, or am I going about this in the wrong manner?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the particular database you're working with.  `sql` could be any number of things... MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle..

Comment: definitely NOT mysql. datediff there only takes 2 args, and `getdate()` doesn't exist either.

Comment: @MarcB - the question should still have an appropriate tag so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition which can be evaluated to `true` or `false`, like so:

```
WHERE        
(CASE WHEN calendar.DW = 2 AND date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-3))
            AND GETDATE() THEN 1 WHEN
        date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-1))
            AND GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple where clause:

```
WHERE calendar.DW = 2 AND 
      date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-3)
            AND GETDATE() 
      OR
      date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(hour,8,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()-1))
            AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: you need parenthesis around your `OR` clauses because the first one contains an `AND`

Comment: For example:  `SELECT 1
WHERE 1=0 AND 1=0 OR 0 < 1` will return 1 while `SELECT 1
WHERE 1=0 AND (1=0 OR 0 < 1)` will not.  At a minimum, it's good practice to be explicit in the grouping of conditions.